# How to add an attachment to email in Laravel app?

Tags: laravel

How to make attachment for external file on laravel mail?

My storage is on S3 and I want to attach it to my laravel mail.

```
    Mail::send('emails.mail', $ddd, function($message) use ($compose_to, $compose_cc, $compose_bcc, $title, $subject, $bill) {
      $message->to(explode(',', $compose_to));
      isset($compose_cc) ? $message->cc(explode(',', $compose_cc)) : '';
      isset($compose_bcc) ? $message->bcc(explode(',', $compose_bcc)) : '';
      
      foreach($bill->files as $bb){
        $message-> attachFromStorageDisk('s3', 'snap/brief/'.$bb->filename);
      }

      $message->subject($subject);
      
      $message->from('hello@b166er.co', env('APP_NAME'));
    });
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

Can please let me know is it a markdown mail ? also please mention laravel version.

You can follow the below code and replace the path to file with a relevant path.

```
Mail::send('emails.mail', $ddd, function($message) use ($compose_to, $compose_cc, $compose_bcc, $title, $subject, $bill) {
  $message->to(explode(',', $compose_to));
  isset($compose_cc) ? $message->cc(explode(',', $compose_cc)) : '';
  isset($compose_bcc) ? $message->bcc(explode(',', $compose_bcc)) : '';
  
  foreach($bill->files as $bb){

    $message->attach(Storage::disk('s3')->url('snap/brief/'.$bb->filename));
  }

  $message->subject($subject);
  
  $message->from('hello@b166er.co', env('APP_NAME'));
});
```

Comment: I edit my code above. it returns bad method for attachfromstroagedisk

Comment: You are missing `/`/ in there `$message-> attachFromStorageDisk('s3', '/snap/brief/'.$bb->filename);` I added it try it

Comment: @TCS I have updated my answer since you have updated your question. This solution works for me, you just need to be sure if the file path is correct or not.